# Air China/Star Alliance baggage drop at Heathrow?

Tags: luggage, lhr, star-alliance, air-china

Are there bag dropping facilities available at Heathrow for Air China, or Star Alliance? I don't want to check in, just drop my bag.

Comment: I am puzzled by the wording of the question. Are you asking whether there's a self tagging + bag drop opportunity for speedier check in with luggage? Perhaps a bag drop in transit like in American airports? Or why are you asking about bag drop instead of check in?

Comment: Yes, don't feel puzzled

Comment: @winsmak: If you want chx not to feel puzzled, how about actually answering his (quite reasonable) clarifying questions instead of just telling him not to be without actually helping to resolve his confusion. Or even better: Edit your question such that it is less ambiguous.

Comment: Then why did you mark as correct the answer that says about the check-in desks?

Comment: Because the link provides the information I was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes** Air China has [check-in](http://www.airchina.com.cn/en/info/travel-prep/destination-guide/17414.shtml) counters at [Heathrow](http://www.heathrow.com/more/contact-us/airline-contacts/air-china) Terminal 2. I'm not sure why you're asking about SkyTeam as Air China is a Star Alliance [member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Alliance#Member_airlines_and_affiliates), but Terminal 2 is also the one used for [Star Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Terminal_2#Star_Alliance) member airlines.

Comment: Most of SkyTeam is banished^H^H^H^H located in T4 at London Heathrow

Comment: Thanks @blackbird, I did mean Star Alliance, confused with China Eastern

Comment: @Gagravarr - what do you have against SkyTeam?

Comment: @Tom Nothing, it's T4 I'm not so keen on! Used to be pretty good, then BA moved out and almost all the long distance coaches + trains stopped going there, bad experiences at security and not nearly as nice as T2 or T5!